# Acquire list of users within a specific group

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to query a list of users within a specific active directory group using PHP and LDAP.

I am making the connection and bind as normal:

```
$connection = ldap_connect($hostname);
$bind = ldap_bind($connection, $username, $password);
```

For this example, the name of the group I need to acquire the list of users from is "Test Group". There is also a OU of "LDAPTest".

I have tried all of the following, plus a bunch of other ways, and I am just not finding the method to get all of the users within the group "Test Group", which has four users that have been added to it.

```
$result = ldap_search($connection,"OU=LDAPTest,DC=example,DC=net", "(CN=*)");
$result = ldap_search($connection,"OU=LDAPTest,DC=example,DC=net", "memberOf=Test Group");
$result = ldap_search($connection,"memberOf=Test Group,DC=example,DC=net", "CN=*");
$result = ldap_search($connection,"memberOf=Test Group,DC=example,DC=net", "CN=*");
```

Comment: These things can be difficult to troubleshoot.  It's been a few years ago for me, but I integrated a PHP application with LDAP and found that an LDAP explorer really helped out a lot.  Among other things, you can usually look at a record and see how it's addressed in that particular directory server.  I looked for the one I used back then and couldn't find it, but you might try this: http://jxplorer.org/downloads/users.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Test Group is in the LDAPTest OU, you can get the group record (which will include its members) with something like this:

```
$search = ldap_search($connection, "OU=LDAPTest,DC=example,DC=net", "(&(objectClass=group)(cn=Test Group))");
```

Note that the user you perform the bind with needs to have access to this group (and to view its members).